# looking for an android code proofreader

Tags: android

I've been thumbing around for a bit looking for some sort of service/website/company/ or exchange that will proofread a given amount of code for general written, best practice oversights, or just outright incorrect code. Does such a resource or service exist (in particular android)? Or am I stuck with the write, compile, and pray all is good method? I could post here, but as I understand it, this is meant for questions that need a solution, whereas I'm looking for a task to be completed, and believe that would be inappropriate. I've gained a little more experience in writing and understanding the code I write but am far from perfect and such a tool could be beneficial. Any links, tips, or direction to such a thing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is off topic for stackoverflow.com. Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com is more appropriate but I don't know; read their help page before posting.

Comment: `write, compile, and pray all is good` Unit testing? QA?

Comment: Pardon the ignorance, never know unless you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For proof reading you can try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

I would also recommend testing your app components. You can use the [Testing API](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) or [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/), amongst many available tools.